# Converting a cURL to Apex Request

Tags: apex, callout, rest

```
curl -X POST https://api.voilanorbert.com/2018-01-08/search/name \
 -u any_string:{secure_token} \
 -d domain="example.com" \
 -d name="Fake User"
```

I am strugging to convert the following into an Apex Request. My issue is that I do not understand what -u is?

I also noticed in postman that the -d will not work when I create a raw body using JSON. It only works when I use the form-data body. Not sure how to create Form-Data is Apex.

Open to any solutions

Reference to the VoilaNorbert Documentation: https://api.voilanorbert.com/2018-01-08/#search-endpoint-post

Comment: I linked an answer that I *think* should fix your problem; please let us know if you need further assistance.

Comment: Define a [Named Credential](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_callouts_named_credentials.htm) with `Identity Type` = `Named Principal` and `Authentication Protocol` = `Password Authentication` and then use it in a callout